# Qt keyPressEvent Error

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qwidget, qkeyevent

I wrote this piece of code, but I get this error:

> "left of '->key' must point to class/struct/union/generic type".

Considering that GUI is a class derived from the `QWidget` class, how can I properly catch the pressing of a key?

```
void GUI::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key()==Qt::Key_Up) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The `keyPressEvent` is declared like this:

```
protected:    
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include

`#include <QKeyEvent>`

then it should work as intended.

---

Apart from that you should use the `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` macro like:

```
protected:    
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
```

---

As @KubaOber mentioned, if you use a C++ Compiler supporting >=C++11 either by default or by you activating it with `CONFIG += c++11` then you can use the `override` keyword instead.

Comment: I'd suggest `override` rather than `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE`, Qt 5.7 doesn't build on compilers that don't support that keyword. I used to suggest `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` prior to Qt 5.7, of course, but now it's unnecessary.

Comment: @KubaOber good point. In general `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` is the safe bet for older versions too :) since he didn't specify the version of Qt I went with the safe bet but adjusted it to mention both ways now.

Comment: Oh...what if I can't include this library because apparently it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Ana are you using QtCreator or Visual Studio plugin / and which version if you're using QtCreator?

Comment: @deW1 I am using Visual Studio plugin, and I have the Qt 5.6 version

Comment: @Ana if you write the include as I did and run it, does the error stay?

Comment: @Ana for completion reasons consider accepting an answer if you feel like it solved your issue in a to you understandable matter. ( you do that by ticking the arrow on the left side of an answer )